# How to run Hbase Java example?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am facing issue with run simple Hbase example.

I have create on HbaseTest.java which create one table and insert some records. In Unix, I can able to compile the java class. by.

$javac -classpath hbase-0.94.2.jar:hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar HBaseTest.java

But I am not able to run this program by :
$java -classpath hbase-0.94.2.jar:hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar HBaseTest

Above command is not working for me. Not sure what is the issue ? Is it correct way to run Hbase Java Example ?

Comment: What do you mean it "is not working for me"? Error message? Does nothing?

Comment: does the hbase shell works ? if not, you have to check your installation and restart hbase

Comment: while running this command I get below error : $java -classpath hbase-0.94.2.jar: /scratch/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar HBaseTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /scratch/hadoop-1/0/4/hadoop-core-1/0/4/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .scratch.hadoop-1.0.4.hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        ...        
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
Could not find the main class: /scratch/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar.  Program will exit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use "hbase classpath" to get the class path needed.

```
    /*
     * Compile and run with:
     * javac -cp `hbase classpath` TestHBase.java 
     * java -cp `hbase classpath` TestHBase
     */
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.*;

    public class TestHBase {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
            try {
                HTable table = new HTable(conf, "test-table");
                Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("test-key"));
                put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("q"), Bytes.toBytes("value"));
                table.put(put);
            } finally {
                admin.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes. It's working 1. Hbase/bin$./hbase classpath 2. Got very huge string for classpath which contain all the path needed to run the program 3.$ java %hbase classpath of string(step 2) ....Now it's working :)

Comment: This works. Both source and instructions to compile & run, on both regular hbase and hbase-slider-app. `hbase classpath` returns a very large string, containing almost everything in ${hbase_home}/lib, and hbase/conf, and hadoop/conf, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If it fails to run you could, if possible, use an IDE like NetBeans to develop Java HBase Client API programs.

- After opening NetBeans, Go to Tools=>Libraries and click on 'New
  Library' and give it a name like 'MapReduce'.
- Give it a name and then click on Add JAR/Folder and select the
  required JAR files, typically under `/usr/local/hadoop-2.x.x/share/hadoop` for hadoop libraries and`/usr/local/hbase-1.x.x/lib` for HBase libraries, by navigating the file system browser(or just navigate to your installation   directories). Shift+arrow keys work to mass select jar files.
- Now create a New Java Project as usual and right click it on the
  Project pane and go to 'Properties'.
- Now click on Libraries=>Add Library and select your library from the list shown.
  You should be good to compile and run them now, given you have all the processes running.